# Validating Bitcoin Payments Programmatically

Tags: bitcoin

Is it possible to anonymously programmatically verify that a transaction has reached *n* number of validations without running a full node?  If so, what is the best means to do this?

Basically I want it to build a payment system where after the transfer is initially detected, the customer sees a message thanking them and telling them that their purchase will be processed within 24 hrs and that they'll receive an email once confirmation is complete.  Then throughout the day maybe run a cron job that checks that each transaction reaches the desired number of validations and if so divide the money between two wallets and mark the product to be sent.  I also don't want it to be with a service like Coinbase or Bitpay where they have control of your coins.

So far I've been experimenting with Blocktrail and mycelium gear.  Both have some elements I like but still not everything that I need. With mycelium you can set the number of verifications but for instance if I want to set it for 6 verifications the customer would have to sit there possibly an hour before they see the next screen.  Blocktrail allows me to query that a transaction is validated but it only has the ability to check that 1 validation was completed as far as I can tell. Can anyone suggest an API or widget that can accomplish these things?  Preferably PHP or if not JQuery.

Comment: "Basically I want it to build a payment system..." No you don't. These are fiendishly difficult to get hard, and even mode difficult to harden against attackers, which you *will* have if it's Bitcoin. Play it safe and find something that gets you 80% of the way there, then add your customization.

Comment: I may have mispoken when I said I want to build a system...I don't mean from scratch  Basically Id like to use the mycelium widget set to 0 verifications and redirect them to a message like what I mentioned and still consider the transaction incomplete.  Then go back and programmatically check the verifications before marking as paid.  So the mycelium option is already 80% there, I just want to harden it to protect from double spends while at the same time not having to have my customer wait around for multiple verifications before they get some feedback and can go on about their day

Comment: For this to be a Stack Overflow question it really needs to be about programming, especially in terms of actual code. I think this is still too abstract and vague, it's an advice question, which is fine, but this isn't the place for it.

Comment: It's just like an if exists question because I don't know and haven't found it in search.  An anonymous api that checks verifications

Comment: It's okay to ask questions like that, we all need to at times, but Stack Overflow has a pretty specific mandate and this question doesn't meet that criteria. A more general purpose discussion forum is best, even a place like [Reddit's `/r/bitcoin`](http://reddit.com/r/bitcoin/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blockchain.info has a simple [Query API](https://blockchain.info/q) for querying how much bitcoin an address has received. You can add a `confirmations=n` parameter that will only include bitcoin that has been confirmed **'n'** times. It returns a simple value in satoshis.

For example to check how much bitcoin was received with at least 2 confirmations at a specific address you could have your code query the API like this:

https://blockchain.info/q/getreceivedbyaddress/1PFtyX9nQvjP8U2N3iUk2oNorzPfpjX9sK?confirmations=2

Comment: Thank's a lot. That's exactly what I wanted.  I figured out how to do it with blockexplorer also but I think I'll use both so I have some redundancy/fault tolerance in my app.

Comment: For valuable transactions it is recommended to have at least 6 confirmations.